# OP has complete self-deletion power. Why does OP not have complete self-close power?

Tags: feature-request

I recently asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151384/finding-an-irrational-not-covered-in-standard-proof-that-mu-mathbbq-cap-0). It got a few votes, an answer, and a few hours later Sivaram noted that it was more or less a duplicate of another question. I agreed, and started to close it myself. But I ended up just being the 2nd close vote.

Why is it that OPs can delete their own questions but not close them? I don't want to delete the question - Gerry has an answer that is different than the answers on the 'original' thread. But it shouldn't really remain open.

Answer (score 6):

OP does *not* have self-deletion power if there are multiple answers or if there is one upvoted answer on a question. If Gerry's answer was upvoted, you should not have been able to delete the question unilaterally.

---

That said, the reason behind the design may be something along the lines that if a question is closed, it is still visible but new answers cannot be added. So perhaps the idea is to prevent gaming the system by using the close vote to block out other additional answers (since existing answers to closed questions can still be voted on).

(Tangentially related, this is why it is often frowned upon to both answer a question *and* vote to close it.)

Comment: Ah - I forgot that one upvoted answer would prevent self-deletion. But I did a quick test, and it happens to be the case that the OP can't self-close even a question with no answers. But you're probably right - it's probably a reputation/gaming the system thing.