# Self-closing oddity

Tags: feature-request, bug, closing

I recently asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648508/25554), and in a comment Eric Wofsey observed that it was substantially similar to [an earlier question I had not seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1578034/25554).

I agreed, and voted to close my own question.  I expected that this would close it immediately, but it didn't.

Instead, the close vote was handled the same as if someone else had voted to close: it was only the first of the five required close votes.  But also the Community Bot posted a banner that only I could see, advising me that a community member had identified a potential duplicate, and inviting me to close the question myself.

This I did, and it is now closed.  But it seems strange to me that the process should require two steps.  I am not sure whether to tag this as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Previously: [OP has complete self-deletion power. Why does OP not have complete self-close power?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4345/25554)

Comment: FYI, see the network Meta post [Self closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321796).

Comment: Thanks.  That's a real programmer's answer, isn't it!